# Cant add jquery to the head dynamically and run jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this code:

```
function init(){
    if (typeof window.jQuery !== 'function') {
        var link = document.createElement('script');
        link.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
}

window.onload = init;

 if (typeof window.jQuery === 'function')  {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(1);
    });
}
```

What I am trying to do is to add jquery script link to the head if jQuery doesnt exist and then run the code. What could be best is to check whether jquery exists in the head as soon as possible and then add a link to the source. But I dont know how to achieve so?

**UPDATE:**
An alternative approach would be using a function:

```
  function init(){
   if (typeof window.jQuery !== 'function') {
      var link = document.createElement('script');
      link.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
      start_code();
   }
   else{
       start_code();
   }
}  
window.onload = init;
function start_code(){
           $(document).ready(function(){
                alert(1);
           });
     }
```

I could basically call a function after everything is loaded.. But this doesnt work well. cause the $ is not defined error is being thrown too

Comment: typeof jQuery will never be "defined"

Comment: okay see update.. i made a few changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function init(){
   if (typeof window.jQuery !== 'function') {
      var link = document.createElement('script');
      link.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
   }
}
```

or use the `HTML5 boilerplate` approach

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

placing this script at the bottom of the page (for performance purpose). Then, if you need to use jQuery function before, just take a look at this resource: [stop paying your jQuery tax](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax)

since `document.write` here is creating a script *block* (which is synchronous) all you have to do is simply

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert(1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That doesnt work. I also want to mention that that javascript code sits in the body of the html and not in the head

Comment: the alert isnt triggered. could I include that script tag in the body instead of html..would it work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YYKWL/2/ your alert is never triggered because 1) `if(typeof jQuery == 'defined')` is not a valid condition; 2) the loading of jquery is asynchronous so the library is not soon ready

Comment: okay that worked. But why did you say it is html5? i dont see any html5 in there

Comment: Thanks, the script now sits below at the footer.. I didnt know that you could put a script link in the body

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13339/discussion-between-f-calderan-and-dmitry-makovetskiyd)